# Absolute Positioning causing odd spacing

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am coding a wordpress theme right now and am experiencing an odd spacing issue.

I wanted my post div to overlap the featured image. You can see this working here: http://www.icc565.com/spring2014/ncdevoe/wordpress/

The issue I'm having is I used absolute positioning to position the post content over the post's featured image and it seems to be adding the amount of space I used to position the post to the bottom of the post so there is a huge space under each one of my posts.

I tried solving the problem by adding a negative margin to the post container, but that made posts that didn't have a featured image overlap with the previous posts. So I ditched that idea.

If anyone could give me any input on how they would go about fixing this issue, it would be greatly appreciated. Here's my code:

CSS

```
.post-container {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.post-image img{
    max-width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.post-content {
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
    bottom: 110px;
    width: 580px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.post-content p{
    font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.post-content img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.post-meta h3 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.post {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

And here's my HTML:

```
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
    <div class="post-container">
        <div class="post-image">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <div class="post-container">
  <?php } ?>
    <div class="post-content">
        <div class="post-meta">
                    <h3>Date: <?php the_date(); ?> | Author: <?php the_author(); ?> | Categorized: News, Television, Celebs</h3>
                </div>
        <div class="post">
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

You can see the issue here: http://www.icc565.com/spring2014/ncdevoe/wordpress/

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.post-content` is using `position: relative; bottom: 110px`. This slides it up a little, but the parent div (`.post-container`) is reserving the location of `.post-content` as if it had not been shifted. You can adjust this by adding `margin-bottom: -110px;` to your `.post-content` so the parent div can compensate for the lost space.

In summary, change your `.post-content` CSS to:

```
.post-content {
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
    bottom: 110px;
    margin-bottom: -110px;
    width: 580px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

**Edit:** I apologize for not reading the php code where you showed that the thumbnail could be missing. You can then use these:

```
.post-content {
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
    width: 580px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.post-image + .post-content {
    bottom: 110px;
    margin-bottom: -110px;
}
```

This makes it so that if there is a `.post-image` element just before your content, it will adjust the position accordingly, and you don't have to worry about messing with adding/changing classes.

Comment: This solves the problem for most of the posts, but if a post doesn't have a thumbnail, then the post overlaps with the one before it. Thank you though!

Comment: @Noelle Updated my answer based on this relevant information.

Comment: Sorry for the late response! I've accepted your answer! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Update CSS like this :

```
.post-container{
   margin-bottom:-110px
}
.post-content{
   top:-110px;
}
```

Comment: This solves the problem for most of the posts, but if a post doesn't have a thumbnail, then the post overlaps with the one before it. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to use an if statement in my WordPress loop that only applied the absolute positioning and negative bottom margin to the content div if the post had a featured image. This solved the issue.